# Can an employer force me to go on sick pay

Tags: united-kingdom, legal

This is quite a long complicated story so I will shorten it.

I am currently suspended from work on full pay. At the last meeting ("check up chat") it was hinted that I may now need to go on sick pay, is this allowed?

Comment: To get any kind of useful answer you will need to give us more details. Why are you suspended? Why do they want you to go on sick pay?

Comment: It really sounds like your employer is asking you to commit fraud so that the money to pay you will come from the government rather than from your employer. Committing fraud is of course illegal, and if you get caught you can be sure that your employer will shift the blame to you if you're the one who declared yourself sick, albeit after your employer asked you to.

Answer (score 1):

If they're trying to put you on [Statutory Sick Pay](https://www.gov.uk/statutory-sick-pay) (SSP) and you aren't *actually* "sick", then no, they **can't** do that. SSP is covered by the government rather than your employer and they tend to get a bit tetchy about little things like fraud.

If they're trying to reduce your pay to what *they* would pay as sick pay, well, essentially, they can't do that either - if you're suspended they have to pay you the [same as normal](https://www.acas.org.uk/suspension-during-an-investigation/pay-and-holiday) and:

> If an employer reduces or stops someone's pay during suspension, this could lead to legal action. This could happen even if there's something in the contract that allows it.

So I'd be pushing back on any such suggestion - they might be trying to play you, or they might be genuinely ignorant of what they are actually allowed to do here. But either way it's pretty irrelevant.

**Don't** give a second thought to trying to appease them here - because in case you hadn't realised it already, this employment relationship is **already** toast. You're *suspended* and they're trying to *reduce your pay*, this is not a job with a future - if you haven't already done so, start job hunting right now and while you do so stick to your guns with your current employer, they can keep on paying you exactly what they're supposed to.